# How to move logic which answers should be shown for user to new class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

For digest mailer purposes I want to get answers which user can see I my app.

User should see only 5 highest voted answers from all groups which he already subscribed.

*Associations:*

```
Answer
  # Returns 5 the most voted answers
  #
  scope :best, order("votes_count DESC")

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
User
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :subscriptions
Group
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
```

So I am looking the best way how to do this:

```
class BestAnswers
  def self.for_user(user)
    answers = []
    user.groups.each |group|
      answers << group.answers
    end
    return answers  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical approach is:

```
class BestAnswers
  def self.for_user(user)
    Answer.where(:group_id => user.groups).best.limit(5)
  end
end
```

However, AFAIK since Rails 3.1 `has_many` supports chaining. Can you test this and report back?

```
#User model: has_many :group_answers, :through => :groups

user.group_answers.best.limit(5)
```

Comment: This looks like a nice way to do it but gives me ``25`` answers for ``5`` groups and should ``5`` with highest ``votes_count``

Answer (score 0):

To me this code seems to belong into the user model instead of a new class.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Return the five best answers for a user
  def best_answers
    groups.each_with_object([]) do |group, array| 
      array << group.answers.best.limit(5)
    end
  end
end
```

For your updated specs tokland's answer looks like a really great way.

Comment: Hmm, yes maybe that should be in User model but i would like to get best 5 answers from all groups not 5 from each one. Is there a chance to easy get this?

Comment: Also using your way I receive: ``[[#<Answer id: 1505...],[#<Answer id: 1506...], [], [#<Answer id: 1507...]]`` So when group does`t contain any answer i get empty array which I would like to avoid.